# How can I break this PHP while loop?

Tags: php, while-loop, bots, irc

I'm new to PHP and working on an IRC bot that joins a channel, sends a message, and then exits.

Everything is working in the script except after $message is sent (line 6), I don't understand how to exit the infinite loop.

```
// Open Internet connection
$socket = fsockopen("$server", $port);
fputs($socket,"USER $nick $nick $nick $nick :$nick\n");
fputs($socket,"NICK $nick\n");
fputs($socket,"JOIN ".$chan."\n");
fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG ".$chan." :$message1\n");


// Begin while loop
while(1) {
    while($data = fgets($socket)) {
        echo nl2br($data);
        flush();

        $ex = explode(' ', $data);
        $channel = $ex[2];
        $nicka = explode('@', $ex[0]);
        $nickb = explode('!', $nicka[0]);
        $nickc = explode(':', $nickb[0]);

        // $host = $nicka[1];
        $nick = $nickc[1];
        if($ex == "PING"){
            fputs($socket, "PONG ".$ex[1]."\n");
        }

        $args = NULL; for ($i = 4; $i < count($ex); $i++) { $args .= $ex[$i] . ' '; }

    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have two loops at all?

Comment: `break 2;` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You need to only have 1 while loop that will stop when a condition is true.

You can read http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

```
while(1) {     // <-- Remove the infinite loop 
    while($data = fgets($socket)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to leave the socket open you need the while. The best way to resolve this is with a callback. But if you only want to break the whiles.

```
// Open Internet connection
$socket = fsockopen("$server", $port);
fputs($socket,"USER $nick $nick $nick $nick :$nick\n");
fputs($socket,"NICK $nick\n");
fputs($socket,"JOIN ".$chan."\n");
fputs($socket, "PRIVMSG ".$chan." :$message1\n");


// Begin while loop
all_data_received = False
while(1) {
while($data = fgets($socket)) {
    echo nl2br($data);
    flush();

    $ex = explode(' ', $data);
    $channel = $ex[2];
    $nicka = explode('@', $ex[0]);
    $nickb = explode('!', $nicka[0]);
    $nickc = explode(':', $nickb[0]);

    // $host = $nicka[1];
    $nick = $nickc[1];
    if($ex == "PING"){
        fputs($socket, "PONG ".$ex[1]."\n");
    }

    $args = NULL; for ($i = 4; $i < count($ex); $i++) { $args .= $ex[$i] . ' '; 

    all_data_received = True //or some other conditions 

    }

    if (all_data_received == True){
        break;
        }

}
```